# Allocating 32-bit integer arrays in 64-bit machines

Tags: c++, memory-management

I have a 64-bit i7 machine.  Suppose I allocate memory for n 32-bit integers.  How many physical registers will actually be used in the allocation:  n, or n/2?

I tried to write the following simple programme to find out.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int a[4];
    cout << &a[0] << "\t" << &a[3] << endl;
    cin.ignore (1);
    return 0;
} // End main ()
```

The output is:

```
0018FA04        0018FA10
```

They seem further apart than they should be.  Why aren't the addresses 04 and 07?  And does this mean that the system is actually allocating four (or more) integers, instead of packing the four 32-bit integers into two 64-bit registers?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Those are stack addresses and it totally depends on what 'int' is defined as for your system as to what size is allocated on the stack. It's nothing to do with registers, which are going to be used for actual operations. To see what the compiler is doing when operating on those values, disassemble the image or have the compiler output to assembler and look.

Comment: Even though you have a nice 64-bit i7 CPU, address are of 8-bit bytes.  Some ancient architectures addressed words (which might be 64 or even 60 bits), but I suspect all modern CPSs address 8-bit bytes.

Comment: The output strongly suggests that your CPU is running a 32 bits program. The i7 can run 32 bits and 64 bits programs simultaneously (if the OS allows it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a 64-bit i7 machine. Suppose I allocate memory for n 32-bit integers. How many physical registers will actually be used in the allocation: n, or n/2?

A 64-bit i7 machine is a x86_64 architecture.

On this architecture an array of 32-bit integers will be allocated fully-packed, meaning the size of the array will be 4n bytes.

If by physical registers you mean machine words, and you consider a machine word to be 64-bit on x86_64, than yes it will use n/2 machine words.

I wouldn't use the word physical registers, this can be confused with cpu registers, which is not where an array (unless very small and optimizer is aggressive) is allocated.

> They seem further apart than they should be. Why aren't the addresses 04 and 07? And does this mean that the system is actually allocating four (or more) integers, instead of packing the four 32-bit integers into two 64-bit registers?

Because the architecture is **byte-addressed** not **word-addressed**.  They are 12 **bytes** apart as expected.

Comment: In C++, **all** arrays are allocated fully packed. Any necessary padding is accounted for in the type itself, not in arrays

Comment: @MSalters: If there were a 32-bit type that had a 64-bit alignment requirement, than an array of n of those items would take 8n bytes.

Comment: @user1131467, the point of MSalters was that the `sizeof` such a type would be 64 bits (thus a value of 8 assuming CHAR_BIT==8)

Comment: The result of sizeof applied to any fundamental type (other than char) is implementation-defined.  When applied to a class, the result is the number of bytes in an object of that class including any padding required for placing objects of that type in an array. (C++11 std 5.3.3)

Comment: Indeed. So, if an array of objects takes `8n` bytes (and `64n` bits), then those objects are 64 bits each, not 32.

Comment: @MSalters: If you are talking in terms of the size that sizeof reports, only if the type is a class is guaranteed padding included - if its fundamental, than its implementation-defined.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification about "word" versus "register."  Yes, I need to read up more to be clearer with the terminology.

Comment: @user1131467: No, it's not implementation-defined. The 5.3.3 bit which is specific to classes refers to padding inside classes, but outside class members. _That_ doesn't apply to fundamental types, for the obvious reason that fundamental types do not have members.

Comment: @MSalters: What sizeof returns is implementation defined for fundamental types (apart from char).

Comment: @user1131467. The exact value is; the meaning isn't.

Answer (score 9):

Each int is 32 bits (4 bytes). 3 of those make 12 bytes. 0x0018FA10 - 0x0018FA04 = 12.

Answer (score 2):

This is the layout:

```
a[0]; // 0018FA04 00 00 00 00
a[1]; // 0018FA08 00 00 00 00
a[2]; // 0018FA0C 00 00 00 00
a[3]; // 0018FA10 00 00 00 00
```

It has nothing to do with register size.

Answer (score 1):

First, use `sizeof(int)` to know how wide is *int* on your system. Then `sizeof(int) * N` should give the number of char your array occupy. Unless there exists what I would call strange systems (because of strange alignment or padding on data which I would consider already aligned... **edit** though 64bit systems may prefer to align 32bit data padding them with extra 32bit, and it sounds almost logical) it should be that `sizeof(int) * 4 == sizeof(a)` in the specific example provided. Of course, likely the array *a* is not kept into any CPU register, but it is on the stack of the *main* function.

**edit**

For example,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int a[4];
    cout << &a[0] << "\t" << &a[3] << endl;
    cout << sizeof(int) << " " << sizeof(a) << endl;
    cin.ignore (1);
    return 0;
} // End main ()
```

on a sparc machine, compiled with Sun CC -m64, gave

```
ffffffff7ffff748        ffffffff7ffff754
4 16
```

Comment: `sizeof(int) * 4 == sizeof(a)` will always hold, there can be no *additional* padding between array elements.

Comment: but not because of no additional padding, that may occur; e.g. think about a struct defined so that its real size is, say, 17 bytes. sizeof(struct X) will give e.g. 18 (or 24) and this is why sizeof(struct X) * N == sizeof(array of N struct X); of course it is right that the padding does not occur in the array but "before", so to say. Though, the "effect" of such padding on struct is visible when you compare addresses of adjacent elements of an array, and it is likely unnoticed otherwise.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that there can't be any padding in a struct (there can be padding both between the members and at the end); that's why I emphasized the word "additional". You, on the other hand, implied that `sizeof(int) * 4 == sizeof(int[4])` need not hold by saying that it holds "in the specific example". It always holds, in fact `sizeof(T) * 4 == sizeof(T[4])` will always hold for any `T`. That's what I was commenting on.

Comment: from a logical PoV, looking just at the part you're pointing at, I implied that `sizeof(int) * 4 == sizeof(a)` iff `a` is declared as in the specific example; if it is not, that expression could be false (e.g. if a is not an int, or it's an array of, say, 2 int). On the other hand, I admit to have put purposely doubts, since I have no a copy of the standard and I am not sure that equation is required to hold for every existing system i.e. I don't know if "there can be no additional padding between array elements" is mandatory or just what happens on most systems. Nice to know it is mandatory.